# Tailwindcss CLI not rebuilding within docker container but builds locally

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, tailwind-css

When I run `docker compose up` it initially builds the css correctly leading to the correct output on the webpage. However, when `home.hbs` is updated, nothing changes on the webpage and the CLI does nothing. Stangely enough the CLI works as expected when ran on my host machine (windows 11) and updates the output.css as I change `home.hbs`. Where am I going wrong??

Things I've tried:

1. `docker compose down --volumes` then `docker compose up --build`
2. Adding the `mode: 'jit'` to `tailwind.config.js`
3. Running the start-tailwind manually on the docker container using the docker hub command line
4. `--watch=always`

Host directory structure:

[image: host directory structure]

Container directory structure (the same except /app is the route):

[image: container directory structure]
Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

RUN npm install -g nodemon

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE $WEB_PORT

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - .env
    expose:
      - $DB_PORT
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init_data:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "$WEB_PORT:$WEB_PORT"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
#BCRYPT CAUSING ERR BC OF OP SYS
```

tailwind.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./views/**/*.{html,js,hbs}", "./src/**/*.{html,js,hbs}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

postcss.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require("tailwindcss"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "promanage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start-server": "nodemon -L index.js",
    "start-tailwind": "npx tailwindcss -i ./public/styles/main.css -o ./public/styles/output.css TAILWIND_MODE=watch --watch",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others  \"npm run start-server\" \"npm run start-tailwind\" ",
    "prod": "nodemon -L index.js "
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "express-handlebars": "^7.1.2",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pg-promise": "^11.5.4",
    "postcss-cli": "^11.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.18",
    "postcss": "^8.4.37",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1"
  }
}
```